# Visible line along Y-axis on top surface

Tags: creality-ender-3

Prints on my Ender 3 V2 have a strange visible line along the Y-axis on the top surface. You can't feel it if you run your finger over it, but can see it which spoils the appearance of the part. While printing there's no noticeable change in the motion of the nozzle as it crosses this line. It happens at the same distance across the build plate each time. Has anyone seen this issue or have a suggestion for how to resolve it?

[image: Print showing visible line]

Comment: That might be the seam. If you view the tool path in the slicer does it change directions there? There may be an option in your slicer to set where the seams appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this. I found a small scratch in the channel of the x-axis gantry (no idea how it got there). The line in the print was at the point where one of the wheels was bumping over the scratch. I carefully filed it down and the line is now barely visible.